# Using sf::Shape with a default constructor

Tags: c++, sfml

I would like to create a class with a sf::Shape as a member variable, but for some reason i cannot set it's parameters in the default constructor, only in main.

Any idea why, the error says "expression must have class type". Thank you to anyone that can help out.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


class SFshape : public sf::Shape
{

public:
    SFshape()
    {
        shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));


    }
private:
    sf::RectangleShape shape();

};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML");


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sf::RectangleShape shape();` looks like a function, not an object. 
So it looks like you are trying to declare a member function, not a variable. Hence, it says it's not a *class type*.

At this point you should not call any constructors anyway. You just need to declare a variable - `sf::RectangleShape shape;`. Note that such syntax `sf::RectangleShape shape()` doesn't call default constructor... `sf::RectangleShape shape` does.

Each member has a default constructor invoked anyways unless it is placed in the initializer list, however you could do things explicitly:

```
class SFshape : public sf::Shape
{
  public:
    SFshape() : shape() //invoke shape's default constructor explicitly
    {
        shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    }
  private:
    sf::RectangleShape shape; // declare a member variable
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
sf::RectangleShape shape;
// sf::RectangleShape shape(); <--- instead of this
```